# What is the easiest way to strip 'iPhoto Original' and 'Faces' tags from photos?

Tags: metadata, tagging, photo-management, iphoto, batch

When I switched to Macs a few years ago, I started using iPhoto to manage all of my digital pictures. I then moved on to Aperture, and now I've just gotten annoyed with the single-file-library thing and I need to move on. Probably to Lightroom. I started uploading all of my images to Flickr as well and they all have the tag 'iPhoto Original' and the Faces feature from iPhoto tags.

What's the easiest way to strip out these tags without removing all the other EXIF information from a folder with 22 gigs of pictures in it?

Comment: Can you post a link to a file with the metadata intact (not Flickr, because Flickr eats it)? I think "iPhoto Original" gets added as an IPTC key, but I'm not sure about the "Faces" feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. In Aperture, choose the `Window -> Show Keywords HUD` menu item. Click on the "iPhoto Original" keyword, and press the delete icon. You can do this with all other objectionable keywords.

Incidentally, Aperture allows you to have multiple libraries. Look under the `File` menu.

Answer (score 4):

In your inspector window, select the folder or section that has the photos with the troubled tag. then in that folder select all the photos for most efficiency (either edit>select all, or command+A). now in the menu bar, select "metadata>remove keyword>remove all keywords" that will take care of the "iphoto original" tag without harming other data you want attached to the photo.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used these command line tools but they may be useful:

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/

And here is a listing of other EXIF manipulation tools:

http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/exifsoftware/EXIF_IPTC_XMP_Software_Metadata_Readers_Editors_Extraction_Tools.htm

Sorry for not being more helpful, but if you try some of the tools please let us know which one worked best for you. :o)

Comment: As it happens, I just used ExitTool to strip some other tags. It's pretty easy and worth looking into.